# Postgres Checkpointer process always running

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL server and limited the shared_buffers to 4GB.

When I insert a large number of records in the database, the checkpointer process start consuming the RAM. This process neither ends nor decreases the RAM consumption even after a day.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. The memory reported as allocated to the process is in fact the shared memory of `shared_buffers` that remains allocated for the entire life of the PostgreSQL server process.

Since it is the job of the checkpointer to read dirty pages from shared buffers and write them to disk, it is to be expected that the process reads a lot if that memory.

If you want to reduce the amount of disk I/O the checkpointer has to perform during bulk inserts, increase `max_wal_size`.

To see how much RAM is still free on your machine, consult the “available” field of the `free` output.

Comment: The numbers I reported is just a sample. Sometimes this can go upto 4GB and then never reduces, until I restart the server.

Comment: To my understanding, after the checkpointer is done writing the dirty pages to disk, it should free the RAM but it never happens.

Comment: As long as it does not significantly exceed the size of `shared_buffers`, that is the expected thing. `ps` is rather stupid in that it reports shared memory as if each process had its own copy of it. Don't worry.

Comment: `shared_buffers` is allocated once at server start and *never* freed until you stop the server. That's the concept.

Comment: I understand your point but these system stats (from htop) confuse me:

During writing a large number of records, RAM consumption - 15GB/15.7GB
| When the writing is done - 15GB/15.7GB (this continues forever)
| After restarting the server - 11.x/15.7GB

Comment: I think you are just worrying because you cannot interpret the output from these tools correctly. What does the “available” field of the `free` report?

Comment: Let me start the script which write the data in database. I'll report this in a while.

Comment: The available field of  `free -m` indicates 3750. This number is usually around 5000.

This will be same until I restart the postgres server.

Comment: RAM utilization is a problem only if the available RAM keeps shrinking.

Comment: RAM utilization is a problem only if the available RAM keeps shrinking.

Comment: Available RAM shrinks and never expands even after the write operation is completed. To expand it, I have to restart the Postgres server.

Comment: Total available RAM becomes less? Try to find out what eats the RAM. Hint: unless you have some rogue extension, and you don'thave  long running transactions, it won't be PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's the postgres `checkpointer` process that is taking too much RAM (after performing write operations in RAM).

Comment: No, the checkpointer process is not using too much memory. If it is, that means that you have defined `shared_buffers` too big for the little RAM you have.

Comment: For a 16GB system, I have set `shared_buffers` to 4GB. I understand that `checkpointer` is taking too much RAM. But isn't the process should free the RAM once it is complete?

Comment: Then the checkpointer will always be shown to use about 4GB of RAM, and of course it will never release that. That is, as I have said, shared memory, and the checkpointer does not have it exclusively. Don't trust the `ps` output. I have said all this many times now. If you don't believe me, ok, go research elsewhere and convince yourself of the truth.

Answer (score 0):

The checkpointer is a permanent process.  It can nap for long periods of time when there is nothing to do, but it doesn't go away while the server is still running.  Most of the memory it uses is the same memory being shared by everyone else.  The `top` command (which I think is what you are showing there) includes all the shared memory a process has ever touched, and doesn't prorate it for the number of other processes it is being shared with.

Indeed if shared_buffers is 4GB, then the numbers you report here are suspiciously low, not high.

Comment: The numbers I reported are of when I restarted the server.